# eventListeneres not responding or dying from DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom-events

To put it simple I'm creating a web app and I'm adding a new `<section>` to the body which is an overlay + alert button and on removal of this section the other 4 listeners tend to stop working which aren't "click" but "keydown, keypress".

```
    function listeners() {
    reloadContent();

    document.getElementById('input-pros').addEventListener('keypress', userSubmitData);

    document.getElementById('input-cons').addEventListener('keypress', userSubmitData);

    document.getElementById('input-pros').addEventListener('keydown', tabBetweenInputBoxes);

    document.getElementById('input-cons').addEventListener('keydown', tabBetweenInputBoxes);

    document.getElementsByClassName('fa-trash-restore-alt')[0].addEventListener('click', deleteAll);

    document.addEventListener('click', closeEvents);
}

// This here is the function called on 'click' events
// The else if statement part was the problem. (Fixed now) please read on.

function closeEvents(event) {

    let tempEvent = event.target;

    if (tempEvent.classList.contains('fa-window-close')) {
        removeFromLocalStorage(tempEvent.parentElement.innerText, tempEvent.parentElement.parentElement.id);
        tempEvent.parentElement.remove(); // removes from UI
    } else if (tempEvent.id === 'overlay' || tempEvent.classList.contains('btn-alert')) {
        document.getElementById('overlay-space').innerHTML = '';
    } else {
        console.log(`Else`);
    }
}
```

Those are my listeners and the listener that's attached to the document I'm using event bubbling to is the last one. I believe it has something to do with the way I add/remove the `<section>`. For now I fixed the issue by creating an empty `<section>` and putting that code within it and on removal I simply emptied that section. If you look at the code below you will see I'm pointing to a specific #ID which is the empty section in the Body{} but before this (when it was bugged) I was simply adding it to the body with -> `document.body.innerHTML +=` which to me made sense since I'm adding a section and I was only removing that section nothing else should have been affected. The only issue I could think of was some eventListeners that would be attached to an element or that section and on removal would be trashed too but since I was using event bubbling this shouldn't be an issue. For event bubbling I tried attaching to both the `window.` and `document.` I know it's fixed I'm here for any explanation of the problem and why it would be happening for a better understanding, thank you.

```
    {
            document.getElementById('overlay-space').innerHTML += `
            <section id="overlay">
                <div id="pop-up-alert">
                    <p>Sorry No Duplicates Allowed.</p>
                    <div>
                        <svg><rect></rect></svg>
                        <input type="button" value="OK" class="btn-alert" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            `;
        }
```